# Checking for MX records using checkdnsrr() function in PHP

Tags: php, email, mx-record

I have researched about `checkdnsrr()` function for checking mx records and found out that mx records for example.com does not exist but

```
dd(checkdnsrr("example.com", "mx"));
```

is giving me true statement.

I have seen the previous answers but in that most of the issues are updated but this issue remains. Please suggest some ways to validate MX records.

Comment: But example.com does have an MX record. https://www.whatsmydns.net/dns-lookup?query=example.com&server=google

Comment: oh I checked on few sites like mxtoolbox.com but they didn't show any MX records 
thanks a ton for the help

Comment: In fairness, `IN MX 0 .` is a "Null MX" so it may be debatable as to whether it should count.